# Cakephp routing 2.x

Tags: cakephp, routes

I am using this router rule:

```
Router::connect('/mp/*', array('controller' => 'objekts', 'action' => 'search', Router::queryString('')));
```

This works as expected!

Now I tried this to add a 301 redirect:

```
Router::redirect(
    '/mp/*',
    array(
        'controller' => 'objekts',
        'action' => 'search',
        Router::queryString('')
    ),
    array('status' => 301)
);
```

but this leads "only" to
http://www.domain.com/objekts/search
the queryString is missing.

Do I miss anything within the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because [`Router::queryString()`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.8/class-Router.html#_queryString) creates an Query String from the passed parameters.

> Query string Either a string of already compiled query string arguments or an array of arguments to convert into a query string.

This means that for `Router::queryString()` to work you need to pass an array or other string to it. `Router::queryString(['foo' => 'bar', 'chicken' => 'nuggets'])` will create `?foo=bar&chicken=nuggets`

I assume you want to get the **existing** Query String and pass it along with the redirect URL. According to the CakePHP 2.0 documentation on [Redirect Routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#redirect-routing):

```
Router::redirect(
    '/home/*',
    array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view'),
    // or array('persist'=>array('id')) for default routing where the
    // view action expects $id as an argument
    array('persist' => true)
);
```

> Redirects /home/* to /posts/view and passes the parameters to /posts/view. Using an array as the redirect destination allows you to use other routes to define where a URL string should be redirected to.

Which means that `array('persist' => true)` should replace `Router::queryString()`.

Comment: can you expain me what the array('persist' => true) does? Is this equal to a 301 redirect? As my first working way does a 302 redirect, that is the reason I want to change it as I want Google to learn that those links are 301 redirects.